# How to set paint strokeWidth in ios?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, graph, flutter-dependencies

> Ios

[image]

> Android

[image]

I am set paint strokeWidth == 1 but for ios platform it's look like above image.
Can you guys have any solution for this?

Code :

```
> paint: Paint()
..color = ColorConstants.grey70.withOpacity(.8)
..strokeWidth = 1
..isAntiAlias = false;
```

I used the master channel, but it didn't work. Perfect work on Android.